# Where can I find the memory monitor that is included with the ADT Eclipse bundle?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

If you download the ADT (Android Development Tools) Eclipse bundle there is a little yellow progress bar that is displayed in the lower right portion of the Eclipse window. I really liked this feature and would like to be able to add it to my normal eclipse install. Any one know where I can find it? My google fu is failing me at the moment. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the memory monitor in DDMS?

Comment: I dont think so. Its the memory monitor that lets you know how much memory eclipse is using.